# wild card and parameter expansion used together

Tags: shell-script, shell

On my Linux machine, I want to remove the directories containing specific words that I stored in a parameter ($LIB_TO_REMOVE). But, when I used the wild card and parameter expansion (first `ls` to check), the shell does not interpret `*` as the wild card. Any suggestions? I'm expecting `ls *${LIB_TO_REMOVE}*` to list the first 3 directories.

```
$ ls
NG-23827_01_AD_02_BI_LS_01_F4_lib390563_6741_1_quant
NG-23827_01_AD_04_BI_LS_01_A7_lib390582_6741_1_quant
NG-23827_01_AD_04_BI_NL_02_B7_lib390583_6737_1_quant
NG-23827_01_AD_05_BI_LS_01_A11_lib390614_6741_2_quant
NG-23827_01_AD_05_BI_LS_02_A8_lib390590_6741_1_quant
NG-23827_01_AD_05_BI_NL_01_C9_lib390600_6741_1_quant
NG-23827_01_AD_06_BI_NL_02_E3_lib390554_6741_1_quant
NG-23827_01_AD_07_BI_LS_02_G5_lib390572_6741_1_quant
NG-23827_01_AD_07_BI_NL_02_F1_lib390539_6751_1_quant
NG-23827_01_AD_08_BI_LS_02_G8_lib390596_6741_1_quant
```

```
$ echo $LIB_TO_REMOVE 
lib390563 lib390582 lib390583
```

```
$ ls *${LIB_TO_REMOVE}*
ls: cannot access *lib390563: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access lib390582: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access lib390583*: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 7):

Your variable is a single string: `lib390563 lib390582 lib390583`. Therefore, assuming (based on the error message you are showing) the default word-splitting on white space, `*${LIB_TO_REMOVE}*` means "all files or directories whose name ends in the string `lib390563` or is exactly equal to `lib390582` or begins with the string `lib390583`". Since you have no files or directories whose name matches these criteria, nothing is shown. Here are a couple of possible workarounds:

1. Since you presumably control the contents of the variable, you can probably safely do this:

   ```
   $ for i in $LIB_TO_REMOVE; do ls -d *"$i"*; done
   NG-23827_01_AD_02_BI_LS_01_F4_lib390563_6741_1_quant
   NG-23827_01_AD_04_BI_LS_01_A7_lib390582_6741_1_quant
   NG-23827_01_AD_04_BI_NL_02_B7_lib390583_6737_1_quant
   ```

   But be aware of the [general issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/22222) about using unquoted variables.
2. Use an array instead of a string for your variable:

   ```
   $ LIB_TO_REMOVE=(lib390563 lib390582 lib390583)
   $ for i in "${LIB_TO_REMOVE[@]}"; do ls -d *"$i"*; done
   NG-23827_01_AD_02_BI_LS_01_F4_lib390563_6741_1_quant
   NG-23827_01_AD_04_BI_LS_01_A7_lib390582_6741_1_quant
   NG-23827_01_AD_04_BI_NL_02_B7_lib390583_6737_1_quant
   ```